# What is alternative of Find_in_set of mysql in Oracle

Tags: oracle

```
select   CASE
          WHEN ComExgRateDetailLog.NotificationMinute = '*'
          THEN
             1
          ELSE
             IF(FIND_IN_SET(
                   CAST(
                      DATE_FORMAT(
                         DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00'),
                         '%i') AS SIGNED),
                   ComExgRateDetailLog.NotificationMinute) > 0,
                1,
                0)
       END

       From ComExgRateDetailLog
```

I want same result in oracle. What is alternative option of find_in set  in oracle?

Here `ComExgRateDetailLog.NotificationMinute` contains value like '0,15,30,45' So query should  be like

```
select   CASE
          WHEN ComExgRateDetailLog.NotificationMinute = '*'
          THEN
             1
          ELSE
             IF(FIND_IN_SET(
                   CAST(
                      DATE_FORMAT(
                         DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00'),
                         '%i') AS SIGNED),
                   '0,15,20,45') > 0,
                1,
                0)
       END

       From ComExgRateDetailLog
```

Comment: redesign your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select FIND_IN_SET('15', '0,15,20,45') from dual would return 2
```

In order to achieve this in oracle use the INSTR function, but INSTR is not exactly the same as FIND_IN_SET. INSTR considers a comma, space, anything inside a string as a character.

```
SELECT INSTR ('0,15,20,45', '15',1,1) FROM dual would return 3
```

You can read about INSTR [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm).

Comment: These functions are not similar: `INSTR('0,115,20,45', '15',1,1)` would return `4` (since `15` is a substring starting at index 4) but in MySQL `FIND_IN_SET('15', '1,115,20,45' )` would return `0` (since `15` is not an element of the comma delimited list).

Answer (score 4):

Not an exact alternative to MySQL's [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), but in your example case (where you only need to know IF a value is contained in a comma-separated set) Oracle's [`REGEX_COUNT`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions161.htm#SQLRF20014) with the regex `'^([^,]+,)*your_value(,[^,]+)*$'` will fit.

Examine the following SQL queries (for Oracle)...

### Examples with numbers

Search for number `1` in the set: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13]`

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT('1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13', '^([^,]+,)*1(,[^,]+)*$', 1, 'i') > 0
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS cnt
FROM DUAL;
```

Returns **`1`** correctly

---

Search for number `1` in the set: [111,222,333]. INSTR would fail to report negative in this case.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT('111,222,333', '^([^,]+,)*1(,[^,]+)*$', 1, 'i') > 0
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS cnt
FROM DUAL;
```

Returns **`0`** correctly

---

### Examples with strings

Search for `'John'` in a set of names:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT('john,peter,jim,kelly,laura,bill,tom,foo,bar', '^([^,]+,)*John(,[^,]+)*$', 1, 'i') > 0
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END as cnt
FROM DUAL;
```

Returns **`1`** correctly

> If you want case-sensitive searches, replace the last parameter of REGEXP_COUNT from `'i'` to `'c'` as per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions161.htm#SQLRF20014)).

---

But if you search for letter `'a'`, it will correctly return zero (INSTR would fail again).

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT('john,peter,jim,kelly,laura,bill,tom,foo,bar', '^([^,]+,)*a(,[^,]+)*$', 1, 'i') > 0
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END as cnt
FROM DUAL;
```

Returns **`0`** correctly

I know this question has been answered long time ago, but it ranks well in the search results and might probably help others that look for a plain but more correct solution than Oracle's `INSTR` function.

### Boolean Expressions

It is also possible to use Boolean expressions, like `OR` or `AND`.

An example using `OR` is the following:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT('john,peter,jim,kelly,laura,bill,tom,foo,bar', '^([^,]+,)*(helen|peter)(,[^,]+)*$', 1, 'i') > 0
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END as cnt
FROM DUAL;
```

Returns **`1`** correctly, as it found "peter" (search for either *"helen"* or *"peter"*).

For `AND` the approach is a little bit different (amends the *CASE expression* instead of the *regex*):

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN
            REGEXP_COUNT('john,peter,jim,kelly,laura,bill,tom,foo,bar', '^([^,]+,)*john(,[^,]+)*$', 1, 'i') > 0 AND
            REGEXP_COUNT('john,peter,jim,kelly,laura,bill,tom,foo,bar', '^([^,]+,)*peter(,[^,]+)*$', 1, 'i') > 0
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END as cnt
FROM DUAL;
```

The above query searches for both *"john"* **AND** *"peter"*. The `AND` operation can be implemented easily by duplicating the `REGEXP_COUNT` expression in the `CASE` syntax, however in return with a small performance penalty.

Comment: Thank you ! It is working perfectly. It is possible to select multiple categories ? Like all john AND peter, peter OR jim etc...

Comment: @jmt I just added the Boolean expression section for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_in_set(
  i_value  IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_list   IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN INT DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       INT       := 0;
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_list );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_list, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result := p_result + 1;
      IF ( SUBSTR( i_list, p_start, p_end - p_start ) = i_value )
      THEN
        RETURN p_result;
      END IF;
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_list, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1
       AND SUBSTR( i_list, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 ) = i_value
    THEN
      RETURN p_result + 1;
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN 0;
END;
/
```