# Passing values to IN clause on a function oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-function, sql-in

I need to return a cursor within a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_cursor (
   bigstring   IN   VARCHAR2
)
   RETURN cursor

IS
  row_test table_colors := table_colors(bigstring);
  c1 CURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN c1 FOR
      select * from cars where color IN (select column_value
                                    from table(row_test));

   RETURN c1;

END test_cursor;
```

`table_colors` is:

`create or replace type table_colors as table of varchar2(20);`

But when I test it passing like `blue, red, pink, white` or `'blue', 'red', 'pink', 'white'` always throws the same error

`ORA-06502: PL/SQL; numeric or value error: character string buffer too small`

on this line `row table_colors := table_colors(bigstring);`

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: what is `table colors`?  You cant do `WHERE var in <string>` you need `WHERE var in ( value1, value2 ... valueN) ` ... you are probably looking for [FIND_IN_SET()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)

Comment: I forgot to mention it's declaration, just edited the question now adding the `create or replace type table_colors as table of varchar2(20);`

Comment: I think is better if you try to explain what you are trying to do. You can't pass variables to Tables and expect a result.

Comment: I want to get a select result based on a `clause in`, which is parameterized... `select * from cars where colors in ('a', 'b', 'c');` I want this `'a', 'b', 'c'` value to be parameterized...

Comment: Then is like I said you need use FIND_IN_SET, but is very similar in oracle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942608/what-is-alternative-of-find-in-set-of-mysql-in-oracle

Comment: But I dont want the position if it's present (similar to substring)... I want to search thoses values as if I was doing a direct query using `where column in (VALUES)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `bigstring` is a single scalar value that may happen to contain commas and single quotes not a list of values.  You would need to parse the string to extract the data elements.  If each of the individual elements within `bigstring` happens to be a valid Oracle identifier, you could use the built-in `dbms_utility.comma_to_table` function.  Were it my system, though, I'd feel more comfortable with my own parsing function.  Assuming that `bigstring` is just a comma-separated list, I'd use a version of Tom Kyte's [str2tbl function](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:110612348061)

```
create or replace function str2tbl( p_str in varchar2 ) 
  return table_colors
as
  l_str   long default p_str || ',';
  l_n        number;
  l_data    table_colors := table_colors();
begin
  loop
    l_n := instr( l_str, ',' );
    exit when (nvl(l_n,0) = 0);
    l_data.extend;
    l_data( l_data.count ) := ltrim(rtrim(substr(l_str,1,l_n-1)));
    l_str := substr( l_str, l_n+1 );
  end loop;
  return l_data;
end;
```

Now, you can realistically implement `str2tbl` using regular expressions in a single SQL statement as well.  That might be a touch more efficient.  I'd expect, however, that string parsing is well down on your list of performance issues so I would tend to stick with the simplest thing that could possibly work.

Your procedure would then become

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_cursor (
   bigstring   IN   VARCHAR2
)
   RETURN sys_refcursor
IS
  row_test table_colors := str2tbl(bigstring);
  c1 sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
   OPEN c1 FOR
      select * from cars where color IN (select column_value
                                           from table(row_test));

   RETURN c1;

END test_cursor;
```

Comment: This is just.....beyond. 

I see many people using split functions to insert each value in a `global temporary table`.. I think your solution is the best approach, or best practice... what you guys think? Anyways...thank you SO much :)

Comment: @MarllonNasser - Ideally, the caller would pass in a collection rather than (presumably) going to the effort of building a comma-separated string that your procedure then has to parse.  Barring that, my biggest concern would be memory.  Collections have to be stored in rather expensive PGA memory.  If this is getting called a few times a minute, having even 32k of data of memory for a collection isn't a big deal.  If this code is getting called in hundreds of simultaneous sessions and you start passing in a CLOB, that might be an issue.

Comment: You can simplify it a lot using: `OPEN c1 FOR SELECT * FROM cars WHERE color MEMBER OF str2tbl(bigstring);`

Comment: @MT0 - Very true.  I believe that is newer syntax though and I don't recall what version that was added in (the original poster also didn't mention a version number).

Comment: `MEMBER OF` is 10g or later.

Answer (score 0):

Please show the definition of `table_colors`. It appears that `table_colors(bigstring)` is returning a value incompatible with assignment to `table_colors`.

As a matter of good practice, initialization of non trivial values should be done inside of the `begin ... end` rather than in the definition section. That allows you to trap the error within the function or procedure rather than the error cascading outwards. For example, rather than:

```
IS
  row_test table_colors := table_colors(bigstring);
 c1 CURSOR;
BEGIN ...
```

You should use

```
IS
  row_test table_colors;
  c1 CURSOR;
BEGIN
  row_test := row_test;
  ...
```