# Selecting rows where cells contain multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Using Oracle SQL Developer 1.5.5.

I have a data table and I'm trying to select rows from the table (TABLENAME) where a column (COLUMN5) in the table contains multiple values. For example using the following command:

```
select * from TABLENAME where COLUMN5=''101','221','429''
```

I'm doing this because I want to select all rows in the table where the  cell values in column 5 are '101','221',229'

An added complication is that in the table each of the values is within single quotation marks, separated by a comma. When run the above command I get an error message which says " SQL command not ended properly" I think this is something to do with the single quote marks and the multiple values because when i run the following command to select rows when column 5 is '443', I get a result:

```
select * from TABLENAME where COLUMN5='''443'''
```

Note that these values of '443' have single quotation marks around them in the table.

My question is what command will allow me to select rows with the multiple values in  column 5? Help!

Let me know if you require any clarification

Comment: Just to confirm, you have multiple values stored in a single field? Can you share some sample data and your desired result?

Comment: A string with quote marks in it looks like `'this is one quote mark '' in the middle of a string'`  *(Two consecutive single-quotes inside a string translates to a single quote instead of ending one string and starting a new one.)*  Your first value should be `'''101'',''221'',''429'''`

Comment: Please upgrade your sqldev 1.5.5 went out in July 2009. 9 years ago. Windows Vista was current.

Comment: For example, column 5 contains cells such as:

Column 5
'443'
'443'
'101','221','429'
'101','221','429'
'101','221','429'
'25'
'-1'

and so on...

All I want to do select those rows which contain the cell '101','221','429' in column 5

Comment: Thanks, what I ultimately want to do is to be able to use the update function to update the fields described above. For example, using my example above, there are a number of cells in Column 5 which contain the following values: '101','221','429'   I want to delete the '101' from each cell - how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use FIND_IN_SET like below:

```
select * from accounts where FIND_IN_SET('101','101,102') 
FIND_IN_SET ignore the single quotes
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: FIND_IN_SET is a MySQL function, and not available in Oracle. Did you mean to use INSTR or a REGEX? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942608/what-is-alternative-of-find-in-set-of-mysql-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

you just need to escape the quotes

```
create table so_col5 (a integer, col5 varchar2(25));
insert into so_col5 values (1, 'abcd');
insert into so_col5 values (2, 'abcd');
insert into so_col5 values (3, 'abcd');
Insert into SO_COL5 (A,COL5) values (4,'''101'',''221'',''229''');

commit;

select * from so_col5 where col5 = '''101'',''221'',''229''';
```

[image]

It took me a few tries, testing selecting the string from dual, but then I remembered I could just cheat - and export the result from the GRID as an INSERT Script and copy/paste the quoted string for that value and use that in my SELECT.

You're using v1.5, which is ANCIENT. Highly suggest you upgrade for an optimal experience.

You can also use the Q function ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617)) which you can pass a string and Oracle handles the quote escaping for you. Here's [a scenario you can play with on LiveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CIREYU9EA54EOKQ7LAMZKRF6P.html).