# SQL: Is there a better way to check if a list of values is in a list of fields?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to see if the values 'PS_BA' OR 'PS_BS' are in a list of fields:

Here is how I accomplished it with a bunch of OR statements.

Is there a better/more efficient way to do this (especially when the lists are much longer)?

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE
     (  ACAD_PLAN_CD   in ('PS_BS','PS_BA')
     OR ACAD_PLAN_CD_2 in ('PS_BS','PS_BA')
     OR ACAD_PLAN_CD_3 in ('PS_BS','PS_BA')
     OR ACAD_PLAN_CD_4 in ('PS_BS','PS_BA')
     OR ACAD_PLAN_CD_5 in ('PS_BS','PS_BA'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is alternative of Find\_in\_set of mysql in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942608/what-is-alternative-of-find-in-set-of-mysql-in-oracle)

Comment: Why do you have so many ACAD_PLAN_CD columns? Perhaps you should consider redesigning your database.

Comment: There are a lot of columns for ACAD_PLAN_CD because this is a flattened database table per person since one person can have more than 1. For this particular case, I could use the original table where ACAD_PLAN_CD IN ('PS_BS','PS_BA') would be easier, but was wondering if my original question was possible in the case that this table were a better candidate for a query in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rephrase your query as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE 'PS_BS' IN (ACAD_PLAN_CD, ACAD_PLAN_CD_2, ACAD_PLAN_CD_3,
                  ACAD_PLAN_CD_4, ACAD_PLAN_CD_5) OR
      'PS_BA' IN (ACAD_PLAN_CD, ACAD_PLAN_CD_2, ACAD_PLAN_CD_3,
                  ACAD_PLAN_CD_4, ACAD_PLAN_CD_5);
```

Comment: Thank you! I just learned that this was a possibility! There's nothing simpler?

Comment: On Oracle, this is the best I can think of.